In React.js, what do I do if once I access a subdirectory in the URL (www.place/subd/ping) BrowserRouter raises "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'"
I'm making a website with React.js (+ Typescript), and I have a Unity WebGL build that works just fine on it.
[EDIT 1] The website is built with create-react-app, and hosted locally in this scenario. (https://localhost:3001)
[EDIT 2] Ran on WebStorm, via a simple npm run start.
index.html has a  connected to App.tsx.
I now added a Router to the website.
Routes: "website.com/", "website.com/ping", "website.com/ping/".
First route works fine, second route works fine, but when I add another slash - creating a subdirectory of some sort that I don't understand - It all breaks.
I am getting three consecutive repeats of the error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
I then open up DevTools, to inspect the problem.
Two errors appear, and specifically this one matters: Build WebGL.loader.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at Build WebGL.loader.js:1:1)
[EDIT 2] (Note that WebGL isn't inherently related to the issue, seemingly.)
I figured this has something to do with the forward slash eventually, and eventually, I found a helpful hint:
In the pictures, there's 2 snapshots of the DevTools' Sources tab.
First is of me attempting to load "website.com/ping".
Second is of me attempting to load "website.com/ping/".
The second snapshot shows that the path to the Unity WebGL build files is messed up!


Here's some relevant code:
(Excerpt from App.tsx)
enum gameIds{
    INSOMNIAC_MOLES = "GAME-INSOMNIAC_MOLES",
}

interface GameSegmentProps{
    gameId: string;
}

const GameSegment = ({gameId}: GameSegmentProps) => {
    return <div>W.I.P: Game: {gameId}</div>;
};

<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<WipSegment/>} />
        <Route path="/ping" element={<div>Pong!</div>} />
        <Route path="/test" element={<GameSegment gameId={gameIds.INSOMNIAC_MOLES}/>} />
        <Route path="/games/insomniac_moles" element={<GameSegment gameId={gameIds.INSOMNIAC_MOLES}/>} />
        <Route path="*" element={<p>hhjalp</p>} />
    </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>

Snapshots of the errors in question:
[EDIT 1]

What do I do?

How are you building and serving/hosting your application? It appears that somewhere you are requesting something and the server is returning an unexpected value. Please [edit] to include clearer details, the complete error message and any accompanying stacktrace(s), and a complete and relevant [mcve] of the code you are working with, including where/how you are hosting/serving the app.

Also FWIW you don't have any "/ping" sub-routes so it's unclear what exactly you expect to be requested from the server and loaded by the client. In any case though the server should be configured to return the root index.html file so the app can load and let the client-side routing handle the URL path and likely render <p>hhjalp</p> since no other route matches "/ping/".

Gotchu. Updated some minimal details.
I'll prepare a proper minimal reproducible example as soon as possible, hopefully tomorrow.
And when you say I don't have any "/ping" sub-route, what do you mean? I'm a bit new to this.
Stuff like "/ping/subroute1"? I mostly mean that when entering "/ping" and "/ping/", I expect both to work, instead of only "/ping".
index.html is indeed returned, with a  connected to App.tsx.
I would've expected "hhjalp" as well, but got an error instead, making me extra confused.

Well, I have just copy/pasted your code into a running sandbox and both "/ping" and "/ping/" correctly render <div>Pong!</div>. I suspect there is just some issue with the way you have configured your server. How are you running and serving the app? Also, is your post about an issue with the route access, or is your post about an issue with the WebGL loader? Try to limit the post to one specific issue.

Fascinating..! I knew both "/ping" and "/ping/" should generally work. The issue is about the route access, not WebGL. (I figured that what I found, related to the pic of DevTools and the WebGL build, might help find the root cause). Will update promptly. You're a godsend, couldn't find nothing online. The running+serving is specifically using WebStorm, with a npm run start.

Well, the errors in the console certainly appear to be all in Build_WebGL.loader.js. Is there no accompanying error stacktrace to give you more details where exactly the problem burps up and what led up to it in the callstack? What in your code is calling/using that file?

Got it!
What I've done is use relative pathes, instead of absolute pathes, for the loading of the WebGL game.
The issue was both in bad understanding of JS, and surprisingly, I did not post enough details to discern the issue.
Before I mark this as correct, it's probably best to wait for validation.
Considering that the 4 WebGL games are in /public/Game Datas/Insomniac Moles/Build/..., I've not realized that the LEADING SLASH, is crucial.
If the pathes started with public instead of /public, as I've done, the pathes would be relative.
In this case, seemingly relative to localhost:3001/ping/.
This would have been discernable here, if I were to post my call to useUnityContext():
const { unityProvider, sendMessage, addEventListener, removeEventListener,  } = useUnityContext({
        loaderUrl: insomniacMolesDirectory + insomniacMolesFileName + ".loader.js",
        dataUrl: insomniacMolesDirectory + insomniacMolesFileName + ".data",
        frameworkUrl: insomniacMolesDirectory + insomniacMolesFileName + ".framework.js",
        codeUrl: insomniacMolesDirectory + insomniacMolesFileName + ".wasm",
    } as UnityConfig);

